# Best way to store chat messages graph database neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

i'm going to implement chat App using neo4j. i'm storing each message as a node in graph but this can result billions of nodes. is it okey?

Comment: Thats pretty vague....What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: store a message as a node resulting  large no of  nodes. can we build a structure having a node  representing a char room and store chat using other method like text

Comment: Neo4j is meant to have a large number of nodes. That's kinda the point. Your question is not clear at all...

Answer (score 5):

Graph database is to store connections between data. It is good for cases which it is designed for. Chat app you mentioned is not proper use case for graph database. Maybe you can use graph database to store users' friendships, which is really good for graph database. But the messages are some kinds of log style data. It is not relationships between data. For chat messages, the date information is more important than relationship. So, I think you may use another DBMS to store the chat message rather than graph database.

Another option is to use hybrid database which support several data models. One of these DBMSes is AgensGraph (https://github.com/bitnine-oss/agens-graph). It provides graph database features including Cypher support based-on relational database, PostgreSQL. So you can store users' relationships in graph objects and users' chat messages in relational tables. So using AgensGraph, you can optimize the storage according to the properties of your data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're going to model each message as its own node, given your hazy requirements, I can think of two likely possibilities for modeling the messages themselves.

One is, for a chatroom node, attaching all messages to the chatroom node with a posted date, and your queries to get all messages in the chatroom will order by the posted date.

Keep in mind that even if you add an index to the posted date on :Message nodes, indexes are not currently used when performing ORDER BY operations, so expect to see a decrease in query speed as the number of messages grows very large per chatroom.

Another option is a linked list structure, where messages are appended to the list in order. You will need to acquire a write lock on the chatroom node (or a head node off of the chatroom node, if always using a head node between the chatroom node and your message list) before appending to the list of messages, to avoid race conditions which could fork the list.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, this particular case seems ideal for an RDBMS system and not a good fit for graph databases.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than saving text messages as nodes in a graph, it's best to use an RDBMS system. They are optimized for this kind of thing, and do it very well if the dataset isn't impractically huge (look into Hadoop, Couch, or something similar).

If you insist on using a graph, try a hybrid database like AgensGraph, which integrates graph an RDBMS databases. You can use Cypher on the graph database and SQL on the relational database.